# “The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate'”

Tags: wcf, windows-authentication

I have a WCF Service with windows authentication is enabled and exposed publicly over https. When I make a call from client, I am randomly getting this error.  I tried all options and almost wasted a week of time. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how do you host the service? If IIS, please enable the windows authentication and Anonymous authentication in IIS authentication module.

Comment: What does your web config look like for any behaviors, bindings and endpoints related to this service?

Comment: @AbrahamQian  - Windows authentication is enabled and Anonymous authentication is disabled. We don't want enable Anonymous Authentication.

Comment: you could refer to the following document about how to enable the windows authentication.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831496(v=ws.11).